# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!})^a$, where $a$ is real parameter

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have to deduce absolute and conditional convergence of series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!})^a$, where $a$ is real parameter.
By Stirling's formula, I got that general term of series is asimptotically $C\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\frac{1}{2^{(1-a)n}n^{\frac{a}{2}}},$ where C is constant. Absolutely, series converges for a<1, but what about conditional convergence?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n:=\frac1{2^n}\left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n!}\right)^a=\frac1{2^n}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^n(n!)^2}\right)^a.$ By Stirling's formula,
$$a_n\sim\frac1{2^n}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}(2n/e)^{2n}}{2^n\cdot2\pi n(n/e)^{2n}}\right)^a=\frac1{2^{(1-a)n}(\pi n)^{a/2}}$$
(without your $\frac1{2^n}$ in front).

This justifies your "Absolutely, series converges for a<1". More precisely, the series is absolutely convergent *iff* $a<1.$

If $a>1,$ the series is trivially divergent ($a_n\to+\infty$).

If $a=1,$ the series is conditionally convergent by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) ($\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}<1$).